# Application crash after UIButton Clicked for Webview load into ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, webview

I develop an application in which i add one viewcontroller's view into another viewcontroller's view. rootviewcontroller has many button on which clicked event add different viewcontroller's view into rootviewcontroller's view. other buttons are working fine.but one button crash the app. 
When we clicked on that button it add viewconroller which has one webview in which one static string is loaded.

```
if(interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    self.uiwebViewAboutUs = self.webview_ld;
    self.view = self.landscape_ipad;
}
else{
    self.uiwebViewAboutUs = self.webview_pt;
    self.view = self.portrait_ipad;
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSString *content = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
    [self.uiwebViewAboutUs loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
}
```

crashreport is here.

```
Incident Identifier: 211D86D5-F375-4CA7-B129-95D26A5E60A8
CrashReporter Key:   99eb9331f18d02387a15d4ad454c75a3cd14ea9e
Hardware Model:      iPad3,2
Process:         SunGroupWP [8334]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F07B0EFA-0A65-4C63-A7EA-AB0D772CECD1/SunGroupWP.app/SunGroupWP
Identifier:      SunGroupWP
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-06-30 09:37:58.489 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x30d0888f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x362a5259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30d08789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30d087ab +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30c7568b -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 235
5   WebKit                          0x354f8043 -[WebPreferences _setStringValue:forKey:] + 151
6   UIKit                           0x32ab6e0b -[UIWebView _webViewCommonInit:] + 1547
7   UIKit                           0x32b54487 -[UIWebView initWithCoder:] + 99
8   Foundation                      0x35b98eaf _decodeObjectBinary + 2699
9   Foundation                      0x35b982f5 _decodeObject + 205
10  UIKit                           0x32b88811 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 113
11  Foundation                      0x35b98eaf _decodeObjectBinary + 2699
12  Foundation                      0x35b99a3b -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1103
13  Foundation                      0x35bba463 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 503
14  Foundation                      0x35b98eaf _decodeObjectBinary + 2699
15  Foundation                      0x35b982f5 _decodeObject + 205
16  UIKit                           0x32b87fc5 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 665
17  UIKit                           0x32af63c7 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 247
18  UIKit                           0x329d3c59 -[UIViewController loadView] + 89
19  UIKit                           0x32949c17 -[UIViewController view] + 51
20  SunGroupWP                      0x0002de55 -[SampleDashBoardForIpad btnAboutClicked:] (SampleDashBoardForIpad.m:261)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x30c623fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 53
22  UIKit                           0x3292be07 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 63
23  UIKit                           0x3292bdc3 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 31
24  UIKit                           0x3292bda1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45
25  UIKit                           0x3292bb11 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 493
26  UIKit                           0x3292c449 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 477
27  UIKit                           0x3292a92b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 319
28  UIKit                           0x3292a319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 381
29  UIKit                           0x32910695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 357
30  UIKit                           0x3290ff3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
31  GraphicsServices                0x3702322b PurpleEventCallback + 883
32  CoreFoundation                  0x30cdc523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
33  CoreFoundation                  0x30cdc4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
34  CoreFoundation                  0x30cdb313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
35  CoreFoundation                  0x30c5e4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
36  CoreFoundation                  0x30c5e36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
37  GraphicsServices                0x37022439 GSEventRunModal + 137
38  UIKit                           0x3293ecd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
39  SunGroupWP                      0x00002afb main (main.m:13)
40  SunGroupWP                      0x00002a80 0x1000 + 6784


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360eb32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d8b208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d84298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30720f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3071e346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x362a5350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3071e3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3071e44a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3071f81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x362a52a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30c5e506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x30c5e366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x37022432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x3293ecce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  SunGroupWP                      0x00002af4 main (main.m:13)
15  SunGroupWP                      0x00002a78 0x1000 + 6776

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360db3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3574df04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3574dc22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360eb0d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d40674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   WebCore                         0x365d84e8 _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 208
3   WebCore                         0x365d87ec _ZL14WebRunLoopLockP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 24
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30cdcb14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30cdad50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
6   CoreFoundation                  0x30cdb16a __CFRunLoopRun + 946
7   CoreFoundation                  0x30c5e49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
8   CoreFoundation                  0x30c5e366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
9   WebCore                         0x3667bc9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d4c72e _pthread_start + 314
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d4c5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360db004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360db1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30cdc3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30cdb124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30c5e49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30c5e366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x35b95bb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x35b95a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x35c2958a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d4c72e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d4c5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360ebcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d46f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d46cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ef79d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdffa70
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00189a70     r11: 0x3f82a0f0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdffa64      lr: 0x33d8b20f      pc: 0x360eb32c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x3dfff +SunGroupWP armv7  <659b6f9f2db23dd8bf689984c930f57f> /var/mobile/Applications/F07B0EFA-0A65-4C63-A7EA-AB0D772CECD1/SunGroupWP.app/SunGroupWP
0x2fee9000 - 0x2ff0afff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30644000 - 0x30683fff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3068a000 - 0x306d6fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
```

Please Help me..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The crash points to a problem loading your WebView from the XIB. Could you right-click on the WebView in XIB and verify the connections? If that doesn't help, could you delete and re-add the WebView?

Comment: Au contraire, the XIB setup finishes and loadView is called.

Comment: `UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:` and the rest of the stack above suggests to me that the view is being loaded from the XIB here. From (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  "If the view controller has an associated nib file, this method loads the view from the nib file."

Comment: `-[UIApplication sendEvent:]` suggests that the XIB is working fine, and that its a matter of events not reaching their proper destinations.

Comment: @CodaFi, I believe there are two view controllers at play here. One of them is loaded and fully functioning, yes. But "btnAboutClicked" triggers the loading of another one, which triggers the crash.

Comment: plausible... I'll test quickly.

Comment: Actually, i made application for ipad and iphone both. When secondviewcontroller is call then it will decide which view will be self.view . there is one webviewAboutus which is assign by another webview_lp for landscape and webview_pt for portrete view.

Comment: Is there any way you could turn over a copy of the app to us (dropbox, github, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The crash is pointing to an unrecognized selector being sent.  Your object has no idea how to react to it.  Whatever the selector that button is sending is, the target does not implement it.

Comment: actually its work fine into ipad simulator but crash only in device.

Comment: So what does the log say when you crash it on the device?

Comment: what i have written here. should i write code UIViewController<UIWebviewDelegate>? Now, i have not write this delegate code.

Comment: That is not the issue here, but yes.  You should probably be the delegate of the webView.  What method is the button calling?

Comment: `-(IBAction)btnAboutClicked:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"btnAbout clicked..!");
    self.aboutUs = [[AboutUsViewController alloc] init];
    self.view_back.frame = self.aboutUs.view.frame;
    [self addViewBack];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                           forView:self.view_back
                             cache:YES];
    [self.view_back addSubview:self.aboutUs.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}`

Comment: @Playcool please use backticks (`) around your code to make it readable.

Comment: Again, please crash this on the device and put up the logs.  You have no idea how much more infinitely helpful they are.

Comment: Sorry, But we have no device. My client tested it on his device and send me this crash report.

Comment: Hm, brainfart: Run this thing in instruments with zombies enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your guideline. i will try using your guideline. Thanks for helping me.